# Extract numeric values from an object column containing floats and floats within a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe.

```
date        price
24-Nov-16   1365.5
1-Dec-16    1392.96
8-Dec-16    1408.38
15-Dec-16   1388.12
22-Dec-16   1507.12
29-Dec-16   1501.72
5-Jan-17    {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025136/Spot-market-starts-2017-with-a-bang', 'value': '1769.73'}
12-Jan-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025228/Transpacific-rates-continue-to-soar', 'value': '1743.24'}
19-Jan-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025311/Eastwest-spot-rates-stabilise', 'value': '1,799.48'}
26-Jan-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025376/Spot-market-holds-firm-over-Chinese-New-Year', 'value': '1768.76'}
2-Feb-17    {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025464/Eastwest-spot-rates-prolong-period-of-stability', 'value': '1738.98'}
9-Feb-17    1717.18
16-Feb-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025629/Spot-market-hit-by-postChinese-New-Year-blues', 'value': '1,572.45'}
23-Feb-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025717/Mixed-rate-fortunes-cast-doubt-on-certain-GRIs', 'value': '1,492.86'}
2-Mar-17    {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025815/March-price-push-fails-to-gain-traction', 'value': '1496.31'}
9-Mar-17    {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025891/Backhaul-AsiaEurope-rates-soar', 'value': '1476.90'}
16-Mar-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL025969/Carriers-midMarch-price-push-fails', 'value': '1390.91'}
23-Mar-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL026066/Third-times-a-charm', 'value': '1350.61'}
30-Mar-17   {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL026151/Spot-market-rejects-latest-carrier-price-push', 'value': '1365.92'}
6-Apr-17    {'type': 'link', 'href': 'https://lloydslist.maritimeintelligence.informa.com/LL107583/EuropeAsia-rates-climb-to-near-headhaul-levels', 'value': '1523.86'}
```

I want to extract the value from the rows which have a dictionary / string and make the column a float column.

I tried, `pd.to_numeric(df['price'])` but I get an error.

I tried coercing it as well but the rows just get dropped of.

How can I extract the values?

Edit:

I also have columns where the values have commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are dictionaries with numbers use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) for `value` for dict, replace missing values by original values of column and last convert to floats:

```
df['price'] = (df['price'].str.get('value')
                          .fillna(df['price'])
                          .replace(',','', regex=True)
                          .astype(float))
```

If all values are strings first parse them to dictionaries:

```
import ast

df['price'] = (df['price'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
                          .str.get('value')
                          .fillna(df['price'])
                          .replace(',','', regex=True)
                          .astype(float))
```

Comment: i have some rows with commas i just realised, i get this error could no convert string to float: '1,540.70'

Comment: @anarchy - answer was edited with `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with this solution:

```
for i in range(0,len(df["price"])):   
    if type(df["price"][i]) == dict:  
     df["price"][i] = df["price"][i]["value"]
```

Basically, you change the old price of the df for the value of the column "value" of the dict inside the df